# Stochastic differential equations with correlated Brownian Motions

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

let's consider an sde of this kind:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:system}
\begin{cases}
dX_t=b(t,X_t,Y_t)dt+\sigma(t,X_t,Y_t)dW_t \\
X_0=x_0 \\
dY_t=B(t,X_t,Y_t)dt+C(t,X_t,Y_t)dW_t^2 \\
Y_0=y_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where t $\in [0,T]$, $T$ is the time horizon , $x_0  \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^l$, b, $\sigma$, B, C are Borel functions and
$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}_t,W_t , \mathbb{P})_{t \geq 0}$ is a continuous standard $\mathbb{R}^d$-Brownian motion and $\{ W_t^2 \}_{t \geq 0}$ is a continuous standard $\mathbb{R}^l$-Brownian motion on the same filtration having instantaneous correlation $\rho \in (-1,1)$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[dW_t^i dW_t^{2,j}]=\rho dt  && \forall i \leq d, j \leq l
\end{align*}
Do the classic theorem of existence and uniqueness of strong solution holds also for this system?
Do you have any reference?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: When you say "correlated", do you mean they are still jointly Gaussian, i.e. they form a two-dimensional Brownian motion with covariance $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$?  If yes then by a linear transformation you can rewrite the system as driven by a standard 2-D BM and everything is fine.  If no then things get much harder and I don't know what can be said.

Comment: yes, i mean jointly gaussian. But the BM are not 1D but d-dimensional and l-dimensional respectively. Does it work also in this sense?

Comment: I missed that.  In general it will work whenever they are a linear transformation of a standard BM, which would be true for any covariance between them.  But are you sure the condition you state is possible?  If I compute correctly, when $d=l=3$ and $\rho = 1/2$ the resulting covariance matrix is not positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you simply need to do a transformation.
Here in ["Modelling the Stochastic Correlation"](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:938934/FULLTEXT01.pdf) pg.23 they give the concrete transformation

[image]

You replace your SDE by the above. Then as usual you need to have regularity for the coefficients (see [What work has been done on SDE with diffusion coefficients of bounded variation in $\mathbb R^d$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432599/what-work-has-been-done-on-sde-with-diffusion-coefficients-of-bounded-variation) for references).

One reference I found online is section 3.3 in

["American-Type Options: Stochastic Approximation Methods, "](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Mip1BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=correlated%20Brownian%20motions%20and%20%22stochastic%20differential%20equations%22%20matrix%20multivariate&source=bl&ots=Q4IVn6Q9o6&sig=ACfU3U0SlBh1uNyju6eevTT9ABdTzZHaxw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibp76d0dv7AhXLnXIEHRQ0BeQ4ZBDoAXoECDkQAw#v=onepage&q=correlated%20Brownian%20motions%20and%20%22stochastic%20differential%20equations%22%20matrix%20multivariate&f=false).