# What work has been done on SDE with diffusion coefficients of bounded variation in $\mathbb R^d$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the $d$-dimensional SDE, $d > 1$,

$$dX_t = b(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t$$

where $W$ is a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion.

I am interested in the case where $\sigma: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ is a bounded variation function, and $b: \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ is assumed as nice as possible.

**Question:**

Has there been any work done on this case? In one dimension, there are existence results for $\sigma$ of bounded variation, and $b$ moderately irregular (Sobolev/Holder regularity). However I have not been able to find much in the multidimensional case.

The reason I ask is I believe I have a feasible plan to prove existence in the multidimensional case under some additional conditions on the diffusion coefficient, modulo several (hard) lemmas. However I would like to ensure that the result is new, and also would be of interest.

One potential application I have in mind is bounded variation stochastic control in multiple dimensions.

Comment: One way to figure this out might be to email people working on related stuff. Have you tried this? If you like, I can ask Alexei M. Kulik from my department when I see him, he is doing parametrix method for SDEs.

Comment: Ah, I do not know too many people working in SDE in person. I would be grateful if you could ask indeed.

Comment: The multi-dimensional case with $b$ of bounded variation has been studied in [arXiv:1306.4816](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4816)

Comment: For bounded and measurable SDE coefficients, it is a classical result that there exists a unique solution to the corresponding martingale problem.  See:  Chapter 6 of Stroock & Varadhan 1997 entitled "The Martingale Formulation" https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-28999-2.pdf

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you! Does this imply the existence of a weak solution to the SDE?

Comment: Yes, this is also a classical result: existence/uniqueness of a weak solution is equivalent to existence/uniqueness of the corresponding martingale problem.  For a precise statement and proof, see Karatzas & Shreve 1991 "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus" Chapter 5 Section 4.B.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis Hi, sorry to ping you on an old thread. But since the thread is related I decided to ping you here instead of writing your email. Essentially the situation is as described in the post - I believe I have a feasible plan to extend some results in the literature considering singular SDE, but the plan relies on several difficult intermediate results. I was wondering if you would like to work on this together. I can explain in more detail via email if you would be interested.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of multidimensional SDEs,

- For bounded and measurable SDE coefficients, there exists a unique solution to the corresponding martingale problem. For a detailed statement/proof, see Chapter 6 of Stroock & Varadhan 1997 entitled "The Martingale Formulation".
- Moreover, existence/uniqueness of a weak solution is equivalent to existence/uniqueness of the corresponding martingale problem. For a precise statement/proof, see Karatzas & Shreve 1991 Section 5.4B entitled "Weak solutions and martingale problems".

**References**

*Stroock, Daniel W.; Varadhan, S. R. Srinivasa*, Multidimensional diffusion processes., Classics in Mathematics. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-28998-4/hbk). xii, 338 p. (2006). [ZBL1103.60005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1103.60005).

*Karatzas, Ioannis; Shreve, Steven E.*, Brownian motion and stochastic calculus., Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 113. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. xxiii, 470 p. DM 68.00/pbk (1991). [ZBL0734.60060](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0734.60060).